# RESTful web service to expose a database view-

Tags: rest, netbeans, view

I am using netbeans to develop a RESTful web service. I have a couple of database views, that I would like to expose through this service. The creation wizard prompts this "You will likely need to specify Entity IDs for selected views (hit can be used)".

My views doesn´t actually have an ID but I still would like to find a way to retrieve them via RESTful. I have tried the netbeans tester unsuccessfully.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ever had this problem. I just added an annotation @Id on a specific field that I want to set to primary key. 
For example, if my class of view has some fields like: **Number**, Student, and ClassRoom. So I add an @Id annotation above the declaration of **Number** field if I want the **Number** field becomes a primary key.
Hope this help